# Debugging flash with gdb-mode in Emacs

Tags: apache-flex, flash, emacs

I'm trying to debug a swf using fdb, the flash debugger that comes with the flex SDK, on Linux. Debugging from a terminal works, but if I do it from within Emacs by doing

```
M-x gdb
fdb -f myswf.swf RET
```

fdb seems to hang as soon as I issue any commands (e.g "help" or "c"). I get no output in the fdb buffer and the flash player hangs waiting for the debugger.

[This page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFlexDebugger) seems to indicate that using fdb with gd-mode should be possible, has anyone else had any luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize this one is a bit late, but I'm leaving it here for posterity: The command to use is `gud-gdb`. You should then run fdb with `fdb -f`. Once you're inside fdb, point the debugger to the swf using `run <path_to_swf>`.